# Why IdToken is a JWT in OIDC?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect

I was reading this question [How to verify that the idToken is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587400/how-to-verify-that-the-idtoken-is-valid) and watching this vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4JIvUIE17c and I got me wondering... Why id token is an JWT if it's meant to be used by the client. Why not a simpler JSON is send back after login? The client will have to parse and encode jwt to have user informations,  but if I understand correctly it doesn't need to be validated as in most cases the client application is registered into auth server and login is done in a auth server environment, and even in a case of a refresh, is commom to use a another refresh token... So I can't see the point to use a JWT.

Can someone tell me why this was chosen as standard for protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using id token, the party has to verify it. Reference: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDTValidation

To verify the token, the token itself has to be in SOME format - it has to follow some specs so the client can actually process it. The authors of OIDC could pick anything - plain json, comma separates string, etc - but they would have to describe how to process it correctly.

JWT happened to be a perfect fit for this task - a format which is well understood and many libraries already know how to deal with it. Hence the authors of OIDC decided to use it.

Comment: I need to study a little more this link, I didn't see a point for client to validate a token received by a request made by they... but it appears I'm really wrong kkkk.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the benefits with a JWT are:

- Having a JWT instead of a plain JSON String has many advantages. As a base64 encoded string, it is easier to include in the query string or added as a response header for example.
- Any serious client application should validate the token signature before trusting it.
- By having a standard format, we get much better interoperability between platforms, services, and languages.

Comment: Yes, the first point is a really good point.